# How do I make a mongo query for something that is not in a subdocument array of heterodox size?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection full of 65k+ documents, each one with a properties named site_histories. The value of it is an array that might be empty, or might not be. If it is not empty, it will have one or more objects similar to this:

```
"site_histories" : "[{\"site_id\":\"129373\",\"accepted\":\"1\",\"rejected\":\"0\",\"pending\":\"0\",\"user_id\":\"12743\"}]"
```

I need to make a query that will look for every instance in the collection of a document that does not have a given user_id.

I'm pretty new to Mongo, so I was trying to make a query that would find every instance that does have the given user_id, which I was then planning on adding a "$ne" to, but even that didn't work. This is the query I was using that didn't work:

```
db.test.find({site_histories: { $elemMatch: {user_id: '12743\' }}})
```

So can anyone tell me why this query didn't work? And can anyone help me format a query that will do what I need the final query to do?

Answer (score 0):

If your `site_histories` really is an array, it should be as simple as doing:

```
db.test.find({"site_histories.user_id": "12743"})
```

That looks in all the elements of the array.

However, I'm a bit scared of all those backslashes. If `site_histories` is a string, that won't work. It would mean that the schema is poorly designed, you'd maybe try with [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Comment: Well the database was made using a php script I made to convert a couple sql tables into mongodb, so if there's a better way to do it, I can change the database over to that in > 1 hour

Comment: Also, I have tried doing the dot notation before, and it didn't work.

Comment: So my worry was justified. `site_histories` is a string. I don't know php, but try to do it so that your `site_histories` is a json array, looking like `[{"site_id":"129373","accepted":"1","rejected":"0","pending":"0","user_id":"12743"}]`. Then the given syntax should work.